# Flexslider preload image getting a stretch for a sec

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexslider

So i'm using Flexslider.

I preload the first image of the slider with JS:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
});
```

The HTML code is this:

```
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <img src="images/Slider/Earth_slider.png" alt="Earth"/>
            <figcaption class="flex-caption-middle">
                <p><h2 class="header-flex">VIDEO, WEB, SERVICE<br>für Raumfahrt, öffentliche Einrichtungen &amp; Industrie</h2></p>
            </figcaption>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/Slider/Rosetta_slider.png" alt="Rosetta" />
            <figcaption class="flex-caption">
                <p><h2 class="header-flex">Die Reise des Satelitten Rosetta</h2></p>
            </figcaption>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/Slider/Showreel_slider.png" alt="Showreel"/>
            <figcaption class="flex-caption">
                <p><h2 class="header-flex">Showreel 2014</h2></p>
            </figcaption>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/Slider/DLR_slider.png" alt="DLR"/>
            <figcaption class="flex-caption">
                <p><h2 class="header-flex">DLR-DVD "Mars-Ein Planet voller Rätsel"</h2></p>
            </figcaption>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/Slider/ECMWF_slider.png" alt="ECMWF"/>
            <figcaption class="flex-caption">
                <p><h2 class="header-flex">Weltmarktführer ECMWF</h2></p>
            </figcaption>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The problem now is that when i preload the image and the flexslider is loaded the first image stretches for a second about the whole browser down. how can i fix this? I tried to do it with a div around the flexslider with overflow:hidden but that's not working.

Comment: Try using `$(window).ready()` instead of `load()`

Comment: Still it's stretching :/

Comment: Add a loading class to hide then remove. Scroll down to the bottom of this thread: https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/848

Comment: Flexslider has base css where the image is 100%, you can apply more specifity on your flexslider such as .flexslider.my-slider img {width:auto;} or whatever

Comment: @BootstrapThemer Thanks! I've tried the this from the last entry. Now i don't have a glitch but my content is moving. The picture is loaded, and when the flexslider is finally loaded the content is moving down a little bit

Comment: Use opacity: 0 instead of display:none. That way the content won't shift.